# Remove word and surrounding line breaks

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is a set of paragraphs.

```
"text text text text text

TRIGGER_WORD 

text text text text text"
```

I would like to remove TRIGGER_WORD and the line break above it, so you will end with this:

```
"text text text text text

text text text text text"
```

I need to remove the line break above the "TRIGGER_WORD" to ensure there is a single space between the two surrounding paragraphs.

So far I'm doing this:

```
string.replace("TRIGGER_WORD", '')
```

But that does not remove the line break

Help?

Answer (score 2):

Match as many space characters as you can after the word:

```js
const input = `text text text text text

TRIGGER_WORD 

text text text text text`;

console.log(
  input.replace(/TRIGGER_WORD\s+/, '')
);
```